# How to set the Privilege for each control and page globally in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, privilege

We have a requirement where we have to set the privilege for each action, control and pages in our reactjs project. We want  to set the privilege in one place of our application. **What is the best way to set the privilege in reactjs project**?

Comment: Can you give an example of a privileged action? What are you validating, and what function would execute if it "privileged" is true?

Comment: @meteorBuzz privileged action like add, edit and update update.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements can be met by using a [singleton store](http://facebook.github.io/flux/), and/or using a [controller component](http://blog.andrewray.me/the-reactjs-controller-view-pattern/). From how you've described it, what you want is to set up some kind of roles & capabilities system that effects the rendered content, e.g. show certain menu options to admins and different ones to unauthenticated users.

Fortunately, there already exists a controller-view pattern in react-router, which you can configure to pass in certain props based on the type of user. This [article](https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1) does a good job in describing how to set that up, using the redux implementation of flux.